# How to write the xpath for an element with specific conditions in a dynamic web table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

https://theautomationzone.blogspot.com/2020/07/sample-webtable-3.html

Please find the above URL for the web table. The table is dynamic in nature.

So here I need to write xpath where it will find the element whenever the name is Jack, age is 20 and last name is Bad. Then I need to click the respective checkbox.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just a table image, and you said yourself that it is dynamic. How can we help you, with no details(HTML code or URL)?

Comment: Sorry I for got to put the URL-https://theautomationzone.blogspot.com/2020/07/sample-webtable-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 tables.

Below is the XPath expression for table 1:

```
//table[@id='table1']//td[text()='20']//preceding-sibling::td[text()='Bad']//preceding-sibling::td[text()='Jack']//preceding-sibling::td//input
```

Below is the XPath expression for table 2:

```
//table[@id='table2']//td[text()='Jack']//following-sibling::td[text()='Bad']//following-sibling::td[text()='20']//following-sibling::td//input
```

**Explanation for table1:**

1. First locate the table using `ID` (`//table[@id='table1']`)
2. Then locate the node which has text `20` (`//td[text()='20']`)
3. Then locate the preceding-sibling whose text is `Bad` of current node (`//preceding-sibling::td[text()='Bad']`)
4. The locate the preceding-sibling whose text is `Jack` of current node (`//preceding-sibling::td[text()='Jack']`)
5. Then locate the preceding-sibling `td//input` element of current node(`//preceding-sibling::td//input`)